# Bluetooth device keeps disconnecting and reconnects automatically

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, asus-laptop

My bluetooth device keeps disconnecting and connecting automatically after few seconds. I have tried all the drivers and reset option but nothing works for me. I have ASUS TUF A15 laptop with MT7921 card.

Sometimes it shows Driver error with the headphone.

Suggest me what should I do?

Comment: Try a different device. If that disconnects - the computer device may be bad. If the new device stays connected, then likely the existing device has a problem.

Comment: @John My problem is fixed now. One user suggested me that this could be due to over heating of the Wi-Fi card, as in my laptop Wi-Fi card is just below the SSD. So I moved the SSD to the other M.2 slot. Now the card got enough space to cool down. My Wi-Fi and Bluetooth both are working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is fixed now. One user suggested me that this could be due to over heating of the Wi-Fi card, as in my laptop Wi-Fi card is just below the SSD. So I moved the SSD to the other M.2 slot. Now the card got enough space to cool down. My Wi-Fi and Bluetooth both are working fine now.